React hook form - Handling default non string values with controlled inputs
I'm trying to create simple form with numeric input with controlled inputs but I'm facing an issue with React Hook Form + Yup.
What I'm trying to achieve is a simple number input, with no value at beginning which is not a required field.
I have simple example form like this:
interface FormValues {
  longitude: number | null;
}

const testSchema = object().shape({
  longitude: number().nullable(),
});

export const TestForm = () => {
  const {
    control,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      longitude: null,
    },
    resolver: yupResolver(testSchema),
  });

  return (
    <Box>
      <form>
        <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined" margin="normal" size="small">
          <Controller
            name="longitude"
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <TextField
                {...field}
                type="number"
                label="Longitude"
                size="small"
                fullWidth
              />
            )}
          />
          {errors.longitude && (
            <Typography variant="caption" color="error">
              {errors.longitude.message}
            </Typography>
          )}
        </FormControl>
      </form>
    </Box>
  );
};

This approach gives me 2 issues:

Error: Warning: value prop on input should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or undefined for uncontrolled components.
input
My resolver throws type error: Type { longitude?: number | null | undefined; } is not assignable to type FormValue

Ok, so let's try to use string.
interface FormValues {
  longitude: number | string;
}

const testSchema = object().shape({
  longitude: number(),
});

export const TestForm = () => {
  const {
    control,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      longitude: "",
    },
    resolver: yupResolver(testSchema),
  });

  return (
    <Box>
      <form>
        <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined" margin="normal" size="small">
          <Controller
            name="longitude"
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <TextField
                {...field}
                type="number"
                label="Longitude"
                size="small"
                fullWidth
              />
            )}
          />
          {errors.longitude && (
            <Typography variant="caption" color="error">
              {errors.longitude.message}
            </Typography>
          )}
        </FormControl>
      </form>
    </Box>
  );
};

Now we also face an issue with typing

Type string | number is not assignable to type number | undefined

The issue is simple, since our schema is not adjusted for strings. But if we change it the way our form demands it, then it contradicts the reason for yup usage.
What is the 'right' way to handle this situation?
I have seen some solutions like this:
              <TextField
                {...field}
                value={field.value ?? ""}
                type="number"
                label="Longitude"
                size="small"
                fullWidth
              />

yet it looks like hacky way to handle some bigger underlying issue.
